# Unsupported use of with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, sqlplus, sql-view

```
create view Captain_Aragna as (with noCommentedProp as (
   select member as nick, title, director, club
   from Proposals
   minus (
       select nick, title, director, club
       from Comments
   )
), noCommentedNicksWCants as (
   select nick, count(nick) as noCommentedCant
   from noCommentedProp
   group by nick
), usersProposalsWCants as (
   select member as nick, count(member) as proposalsCant
   from Proposals
   group by member
), finalJoin as (
   select *
   from noCommentedNicksWCants
   join usersProposalsWCants
   using (nick)
)select nick, noCommentedCant/proposalsCant*100 as Porcentaje
from finalJoin);
```

Can someone help me with this error, i done know how to create a view and make a with inside, also when i make this with the view, it selects the clumns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following syntax could work:

```
create view Captain_Aragna as 
with 
    noCommentedProp as (
       select member as nick, title, director, club
       from Proposals
       minus (
           select nick, title, director, club
           from Comments
       )
    ), 
    noCommentedNicksWCants as (
       select nick, count(nick) as noCommentedCant
       from noCommentedProp
       group by nick
    ), 
    usersProposalsWCants as (
       select member as nick, count(member) as proposalsCant
       from Proposals
       group by member
    ), 
    finalJoin as (
       select *
       from noCommentedNicksWCants
       join usersProposalsWCants
       using (nick)
    )
select nick, noCommentedCant/proposalsCant*100 as Porcentaje
from finalJoin
```